# Mount Ubuntu, creating Raid 1 with the installment configuration

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, uefi, raid

install Ubuntu using Raid 1 configuration with two disk.

In doing so, two partitions were created in each disk, that of the RAID and the EFI starter.

If I lose an disk, the other is operational.

How do I set the RAID again to integrate the new disk with its two partitions, that of the RAID and the EFI start.